# Изменить цвет текста Toolbar вообще возможно?

Tags: android-toolbar, toolbar

Пробовал через стили и через код, цвет не меняется, все время белый, minSdkVersion 19 и targetSdkVersion 27

У меня такой стиль

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

в layout такой код

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                     />
```

Comment: Возможно.......

Comment: и как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Например так

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="@color/toolbar"/>
```